# Is it possible to update multiple apps through some sort of api?

Tags: android, google-play, publish

Would it be possible to upload multiple apps in the google play store and app store through some sort of api?

I would like it if I were able to write a script that updates all my apps with a new apk, is that possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google play has an api:

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started

Yo can use it to create your own script, but maybe you need something like this:

https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher